# Android hide status bar of traslucant screen

Tags: android

Android hide status bar of traslucant screen please give me the solution.

```
<style name="Theme.Hello" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

and I have tried only by setting the theme `"android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` in manifest file but I'm getting background screen black color.

Comment: Clarify you question. What do you need?

Comment: Sorry you really need to clarify your question. At the moment it is not possible to understand your problem.

Comment: If you want to create an app that is transparent/translucent you are going to have a lot of difficulty. As far as I know this is not possible.

Comment: i want to hide status bar in the screen and screen is translucant